# Best way to get the command line of a process in Unix

Tags: perl, unix

I know about [`Proc::ProcessTable`](http://metacpan.org/module/Proc::ProcessTable). My problem is performance: I need to get the result quickly. With `Proc::ProcessTable`, it looks like this:

```
foreach $p (@{$t->table}) {...}
```

So I have to do a full scan through several thousands entries, just to find a process by pid and get the information I am interested in. It's slow. Is there a better way?

I know about the `ps` command as well, but I am looking for a Perl solution.

Comment: Did you search CPAN? Did you see http://search.cpan.org/~jettero/Unix-Process-1.3101/Process.pm?

Comment: No, I did not. Sorry. I just tried Process.pm - it works Ok but it's a wrapper arount ps command. If I don't find anything better then probably will use it. Or maybe I will just use ps to avoid extra dependencies for the project. Thank you!

Comment: I'm surprised you're finding that searching for a process with a given PID is slow, especially if you're using the command-line where it often takes longer to type a command than execute it. Checking thousands of in-memory values will take very little time at all, especially when much of the code is written in C, as it is for `Proc::ProcessTable`

Comment: By the way, you want `my ($proc) = grep { $_->pid == $mypid } @{$t->table}` to find a process with a given PID, or `my %procs = map { $_->pid => $_ } @{$t->table}` to create a hash that maps all PIDs to their process data, after which you could write `print $procs{$mypid}->cmndline`

Comment: It's funny that module does not include such convenience methods.

Comment: You are right. Proc::ProcessTable approach works faster.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, I like to read the `/proc/<pid>/cmdline` virtual file.

```
$pid = 1234;
open my $fh, '<', "/proc/$pid/cmdline";
my $cmdline = <$fh>;   # rare to see \n in cmdline. Unset $/ if ur paranoid
close $fh;
@cmd = split /\0+/,$cmdline;
```

Comment: I need some universal solution. I will mostly run it on AIX. There is /proc/<pid>/psinfo on AIX, but it's a binary format.